# Switching between 2 frameworks on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using [Skype for Business App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/appsdk/skypeappsdk) for iOS which came into two versions: one for iOS Devices and another for iOS Simulator.

I cannot use both frameworks at the same time, so I have to delete simulator version and add device version to run my app on device and I do the opposite if I want to run my app on simulator.

My question: is there a way in Xcode to switch between frameworks without deleting them from project?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a fat library for development. You can get it with a command like the one below:

```
lipo -create Release-iphoneos/libMobileVLCKit.a Release-iphonesimulator/libMobileVLCKit.a -o libMobileVLCKit.a
```

Here the `libMobileVLCKit.a`is a fat library. When you're done with development you can link only the library which was compiled for the real device.